# MySQL Add Result Column Between Table Join

Tags: mysql

I have a query which combines columns from two tables like so:

```
SELECT UR.recordId, UR.userName, UN.note
FROM userRecords UR
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT UR2.recordId
    FROM userRecords UR2
    WHERE userId = 17
) AS URX USING (recordId)
LEFT JOIN userNotes UN USING(recordId);
```

This produces a result set that has one row for every record in the 'userNotes' table, which has the same recordId from the 'userRecords table like so:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| recordId | userName | note                     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 17       | Rob S    | apples                   |
| 17       | Rob S    | oranges                  |
| 17       | Rob S    | grapes                   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

This is the desired output. However, I would now like to add a column named 'hasPhotos' in between the userName and note columns, which will indicate whether there are any records in the 'userPhotos' table that also have the same recordId (17).

The 'userPhotos' table can contain anywhere from 0 to N records with the matching recordId, just like the userNotes table. However, I want the 'hasPhotos' column to simply indicate "false" if there are no matching records and "true" if there are 1 or more matches. I also do not want the number of rows in the result set to increase based on the number of records in the 'userPhotos' table. The number of total rows should still match the number of records found in the 'userNotes' table.

So, if there are NO matching photo records it should look like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| recordId | userName | hasPhotos | note         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 17       | Rob S    | false     | apples       |
| 17       | Rob S    | false     | oranges      |
| 17       | Rob S    | false     | grapes       |
--------------------------------------------------
```

And if there are 1 or more matching photo records it should look like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| recordId | userName | hasPhotos | note         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 17       | Rob S    | true     | apples        |
| 17       | Rob S    | true     | oranges       |
| 17       | Rob S    | true     | grapes        |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone please assist on how I could adjust my query to accomplish this? I tried various ways but get undesirable results such as increasing the number of rows based on the matching photo records...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend adding sample data for the table in question.  You have only showed us the output, and many may find it hard to follow your intended logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an EXISTS condition with a correlated subquery.

Also, it looks to me like the RIGH JOIN is not needed in the existing query.

I would do :

```
SELECT 
    UR.recordId, 
    UR.userName, 
    UN.note,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM userPhotos UP
        WHERE UP.recordId = UR.recordId
    ) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END hasPhotos
FROM userRecords UR
LEFT JOIN userNotes UN USING(recordId)
WHERE UR.userId = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the query -

```
SELECT UR.recordId, UR.userName, case when UP.recordId is null then false else true , UN.note
FROM userRecords UR
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT UR2.recordId
    FROM userRecords UR2
    WHERE userId = 17
) AS URX USING (recordId)
LEFT JOIN userNotes UN USING(recordId)
left join (select distinct recordId from userPhotos) UP on UR.recordId=UP.recordId
```